# Deserializing key value pair into list

Tags: c#, json, json.net, deserialization

Can anyone please show me how to deserialize key-value pair into a list? i.e. From the JSON response, I want to get out the list of countries and code from below response. I am using Newtonsoft.Json:

```
{
    "status": "SUCCESS",
    "message": "something",
    "data": {
        "trade_origin_iso3country": "GBR",
        "countries": {
            "ARM ": "Armenia",
            "BLR": "Belarus ",
            "DNK": "Denmark",
            "GBR": "United Kingdom",
            "MCO": "Monaco"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Deserialise it as a dictionary<string, string>

Comment: You could use `JObject.Parse(json)` and then `obj["data"]["countries"]` and convert it to `Dictionary`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend custom types if that's possible.  Here's a console app you can copy and paste that shows you what I'm referring to using the information you've provided.  *It uses the well known and highly recommended `Newtonsoft.Json` nuget package.*

**Code:**

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Question_Answer_Console_App
{
    public class Program
    {
        public const string JsonResultString = @"{
                                                     ""status"": ""SUCCESS"",
                                                     ""message"": ""something"",
                                                     ""data"": {
                                                         ""trade_origin_iso3country"": ""GBR"",
                                                         ""countries"": {
                                                             ""ARM"": ""Armenia"",
                                                             ""BLR"": ""Belarus "",
                                                             ""DNK"": ""Denmark"",
                                                             ""GBR"": ""United Kingdom"",
                                                             ""MCO"": ""Monaco""
                                                         }
                                                     }
                                                 }";
        [STAThread]
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var jsonResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonResult>(JsonResultString);

            foreach (var keyValue in jsonResult.Data.Countries)
                Console.WriteLine($"{keyValue.Key} : {keyValue.Value}");

            Console.Read();
        }
    }

    public class JsonResult
    {
        public string Status { get; set; }
        public string Message { get; set; }
        public JsonData Data { get; set; }
    }

    public class JsonData
    {
        [JsonProperty("trade_origin_iso3country")]
        public string TradeOriginIso3country { get; set; }
        public Dictionary<string, string> Countries { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Outputs:**

```
ARM : Armenia
BLR : Belarus
DNK : Denmark
GBR : United Kingdom
MCO : Monaco
```

Answer (score 3):

If you create a class with the following definition:

```
public class MyObject 
{
     public string status { get; set; }
     public string message { get; set; }
     public MySubObject data { get; set; }
}

public class MySubObject 
{
    public string trade_origin_iso3country { get; set;}
    public Dictionary<string,string> countries { get;set;}
}
```

You can just use the most convenient ( at least IMO) syntax to get an object with a filled dictionary.

```
var myResult = JsonConvert.Deserialize<MyObject>(json);
```

To get a list:

```
var result = (
     from kvp in myResult.data.countries
     select $"{kvp.Key}: {kvp.Value}").ToList()
```

Comment: This also gave me the result I wanted. Thanks for the swift response

Answer (score 0):

You could use `JObject.Parse` to parse json to `JObject` and then access the inner property and convert it to `Dictionary<string, string>`:

```
var countries = JObject.Parse(json)["data"]["countries"].ToObject<Dictionary<string, string>>();
foreach (var kv in countries)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Key[{kv.Key}] Value[{kv.Value}]");
}
```

Will output:

```
Key[ARM] Value[Armenia]
... etc.
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(json);

foreach(var kv in data)
{
Console.WriteLine(kv.Key + ":" + kv.Value);
}
```

try this

Comment: Will this work?  I believe he would need to get the inner type first which I recommend a custom type or dynamic type and then passing into dictionary. Json result will have 3 objects with the third object, data, that can be a dictionary<string, string>

Comment: I did try this and it doesn't work.  I was curious if Newtonsoft had some clever variable type name to help with conversion feature I was unaware of but nope.